# Objective C: I need some advice regarding properties vs ivars

Tags: objective-c, properties, ivar

I looked up my current problem on stackoverflow and many other website outlets, but I am a little confused to be quite honest. Should I only use properties when another class needs access to it and ivars when it is being used for only my private class? This is what I am getting so far, although I did hear some other things about when to use ivars and properties. I am just trying to keep my code clean and more modern. Any clarification will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very opinion based topic. So I'm trying to stay with **uncontroversial** facts and advice:

- Never access ivars from outside of the class. Public access would always be done through properties and their accessors or other methods. Nowadays headers should never contain ivar declarations.
- Using ivars internally is possible and not uncommon. ARC makes this easy for object types, as ownership is handled automatically.
- Using properties gives you proper ownership handling for `NSString`, `NSArray` et al. (`copy`).
- Also, in some cases they can help with thread safety (`atomic`).
- Using properties internally could make KVO compliance or other side effects easier to implement.
- Using private properties is the standard pattern for exposing IBOutlets.
- Properties can be queried during runtime. This is seldom needed, though.
- Private properties have the problem of polluting the method namespace for a class. Unintentional overrides can occur.

The actual decision whether or not to use ivars in the implementation is a matter of personal preference. It is affected by many subtle details from code style.

Comment: Ivars can be queried during runtime, too.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Yes, but they carry a lot less static information.

Comment: @Alistra I appreciate your suggested edit, but in this controversial case I prefer if you'd add another post with your points.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe, I would add that ivars should be used in `init`/`dealloc` (according to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW4)). I, personally, believe it's the only case when ivars should be used. But your list of pluses/minuses is more versatile.

Comment: @FreeNickname I consider this specific advice from Apple 1. opinionated (they don't give any explanation or reason) and 2. not applicable (the document is about manual retain release code, not ARC). Being such a controversial item, I prefer not to add it to my list.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe, I don't remember where I read it, but the reason behind this advice, as far as I remember, is KVO. If some observer tracks changes in certain properties and values of those properties are set in `init`/`dealloc`, the observer might try to work with partially initialized/partially uninitialized object. It's not very likely that there is an observer already, while we are in an `init` method, but it's possible. It might be added in the `super` initializer, for instance.

Comment: That advice from Apple was connected to the fact that property setters dont have to be trivial and can access other properties.  During init and dealloc the internal state of the object is incomplete and nontrivial setters can work incorrectly. On the other hand, not using setters in init can lead to corrupted states, too. That's why I ignore Apple's advice, I am using setters everywhere and solve problems only when I actually encounter them.

Comment: @FreeNickname 1. You should never follow a rule, if you don't know the reasons. 2. There are two advices: a) KVO – this advice is simply wrong, because there can *never* be an observation on an instance, that is in an initialization process. How? KVO in `+alloc`? b) There might be a problem with overwritten setters. However, if this is a problem, the rule should be "Don't use methods while initializing" which is aa) ridiculous and bb) people infringes this rule very often. 3) So let's go back to 1): You should never follow a rule, if you don't know the reasons.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, 1. Agree. 2. `addObserver` in `super init`. I wrote it in my comment. Not very likely, but possible. Sulthan added a more plausible version about overridden setters. When you call a method, you understand, that this method might work with ivars, which are not yet initialized. The setter is called implicitly. And it might or might not be overridden, you never know. Anything in the world can be happening in a category for your class, that you don't control. And it's hard to write a category, if you have to keep in mind the initialization order. And I'm out of characters.

Comment: As I wrote every method can be overwritten in a subclass, causing the problem, that the usage of any method in base' init makes subclass' instance find itself akin of not completely initialized. Setting an ivar in a subclass can cause at least as many problems. Furthermore the setter is not called "implicitly", but explicitly in the base' init – or somewhere else.  "Anything in the world" might happen in a category. During initialization or later. So this is a reason *not* to rely on a special order, but to write robust setters. The only way to deal with that is to keep it in mind.

Comment: BTW: self observation is akin of cancer and should only be done, if there is really no other way to deal with a problem. *This* is an anti pattern.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, well, [some people believe](http://qualitycoding.org/objective-c-init/) that you shouldn't send any messages to self in `init`/`dealloc`, actually. By implicitly I mean that dot syntax is a syntax sugar that obscures message sending. The point is that I see near to none advantages of using properties in `init`/`dealloc` and near to none disadvantages of using `ivars`. Considering, that an official recommendation of the language creators tells me to use ivars, why wouldn't I? Because I'm too clever to do so?)

Comment: Using dot notation or explicit messages is without any meaning to this discussion. Of course some people say that. (They are in the minority, while the people saying not to use setters are in the majority. Strange.) But this recommendation is *not* told by the language creators. Alan Kay ist the language creator and he never had said something like this. This advice is very young (1, 2 years, IIRC). In my books I wrote several advise against Apple's documentation – and Apple independently changed the docs. (I. e. the, eh, very special underscored ivars rule of Apple, usage of `-release`, …)

Comment: While for the disadvantage you need a very special and unlikely scenario, the advantages of using setters are obvious: 1. You use everywhere setters. Exceptions are ugly. 2. The assignment to an ivar depends on the type of the property (`weak`, `strong` vs. `copy`), because one can expect that the init argument is copied, if you have a copy property. So the information, whether you have to copy the value is repeated. "Don't repeat yourself" is a rule accepted by nearly all devs.

Comment: 3. You cannot hold the rule in subclasses: If you set a superclass' property, you have to use setters (or to publish the ivar to subclasses, eh, …) If you use setters, you get the "problem" in subsubclasses, because then the subclass uses setters. So for subclassing you have an exception of the exception. You will find yourself with a rule (use setters) + an exception (don't use it in `-init…`) + an exception-exception (but do it in `-init…`, setting a base class' property) instead of having a simple rule. What for? For self observation? For overwritten setters?

Comment: So you get the obvious advantages in 100 % of your code, but the "disadvantages" (not for me: This is simply the nature on inheritance, accepted in all cases outside initialization) in unlikely scenarios.  BTW: If there is documentation of clang (the compiler creators) and Apple about Objective-C, *always* read the clang documentation. This is good for your code.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, DRY is a good argument. I could provide counter arguments for everything else. But we disagree on setters/sending messages to `self`. I believe that it is a good argument, you don't. I guess, there is no point in continuing this discussion, and Nikolai Ruhe was right after all: it is opinionated. P.S. Please, use @ to call your opponent, otherwise he/she doesn't receive notifications. Also, Alan Kay created Smalltalk, not Obj-C. And you're not the only person in the world who reads Clang docs. And Clang is not the only Obj-C compiler. Still, thank you for the dialog.

Comment: And for exactly the same reason I did not discuss that further in my answer, but simply said, what most developers do. Tricky me. Yes, Brad Cox, my fault. Didn't work at Apple's, too at this time. And of course clang is not the only manufacture of compilers. But Apple is *no* manufacture of compilers. (Despite some changes to they made to the clang base before delivering it in Xcode.)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion - you should only use properties, which are backed by an ivar if you didn't override the getter and the setter.

You should declare them in the public interface to make them public, and declare them in the private interface, that's right, to make them private.

There are many advantages to this, some are:

1. Perform lazy instantiation in the getter
2. Do validation in the setter
3. Make a property readonly public and readwrite privately

Within your class, you should **almost** always access your properties through the getter/setter unless:

1. You want to avoid the behavior you implemented in these methods (lazy instantiation, validation)
2. You are in the initializer
3. You are in the getter/setter

Here's an example of how of some of the following points:

```
@interface SomeObject : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * objects;
@property (readonly, nonatomic, getter=isActive) BOOL active; // Public read-only 
@end

@interface SomeObject()
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, getter=isActive) BOOL active; // Can be updated internally
@property (nonatomic, getter=isVisible) BOOL visible;
@end

@implementation SomeObject

- (NSMutableArray)objects {
   if (!_objects) {
      _objects = [NSMutableArray array]; // Lazy instantiate when first accessed
   }
   return _objects;
}

- (BOOL)isActive {
   return _isActive && self.isVisible; // Cannot be active if not visible
}

- (BOOL)setActive:(BOOL)active {
   self.visible = active; // Keep visibility same as active
   _active = active;
}

-(BOO)setVisible:(BOOL)visible {
   _visible = visible;
   // perform animation or something else...
}

@end
```

Any of this cannot be achieved using ivars.

Answer (score -2):

You should use declared properties inside and outside your class. Most developers say that you should only set the ivar behind a property in initializers. (I do not agree and use setters and getters in this case, too, but I'm in minority.)

Comment: It's not only "most developers". It's actually Apple who says so. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW4). Look at `Don’t Use Accessor Methods in Initializer Methods and dealloc`.

Comment: I know that. Do you know that Apple itself does not follow that rule, i. e. at `NSView`. However, following a rule without giving reasons is never a proof for something except the absence of an own brain.

Comment: from your last response above ("tricky me") I figured, that you think that I considered your answer bad and I was the one who downvoted it. So, just to clarify: I wasn't the one who originally downvoted it. I didn't downvote it after writing my comment. I did downvote it though after reading your reply about absence of an own brain. Because I can't downvote comments. You can hate me for it if you like, but I believe that trying to offend people is not the way to defend your position. And once again, use @<name_here>, please.

Comment: No, I do not consider that. And I do not know, whether you can downvote or not. And I do  not hate people for upvotes, downvotes, comments, or anything else that can happen on SO.